# Converting -190.25 to signed binary?

Tags: binary, binary-operations

Converting -190.25 to decimal, my first step is to change it to -191 + 0.75

0.75 = .11 in binary

191 = 010111111 in signed binary
-191 = 101000001 in signed binary using 2s complement (not sure about this part)

And adding together gives 101000001.11
However the answer given is 11101000001.110 and I have a couple of questions.

1) Why is the decimal represented in 11 bits?
2) Why is the 0 added at the 3rd decimal place?

I have been stuck a long time on this question and would really appreciate a step by step solution. Cheers.

Comment: Really a computer science question not mathematics: $-190.25$ decimal is $-10111110.01$ binary.

Comment: You need to define the format you are using.  There are many for negative integers-1s complement, 2s complement, sign/magnitude.  The simplest version of these are for integers only.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, I am using 2's complement form